# Windows export PATH configuration

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, path

I have many variables in the PATH and I want to export and reuse them.

Is that possible? (something like a .reg file)

Comment: Path is just one variable. At the command line type: `echo %PATH%` to see it's value. Nearly all languages support a way to access environmental variables already but you haven't asked for anything specific. If you want all of them type: `SET`

Comment: @krowe Works perfect! Many thanks. And if I want to revert I'll type: `SET %PATH% "paths"`?

Comment: Type `SET TMP=%PATH%` to create a new copy for just this session. Type `SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\newdir` to append.

Comment: @krowe Perfect! Write it as an answer to approve it. btw it was so dum question for the downvotes?

Comment: It'll probably get deleted\merged because I'm sure this has been asked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearly all languages support a way to access environmental variables already but you haven't asked for anything specific so we'll assume that you want to do this from the command line. Path is just one variable. At the command line type: `echo %PATH%` to see it's value.

If you want all of the environmental variables listed then type: `SET` by itself.

Type `SET TMP=%PATH%` to create a new copy for just this session.

Type `SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\newdir` to append to it.

To loop through %PATH% use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471556/pretty-print-windows-path-variable-how-to-split-on-in-cmd-shell): `for %a in ("%path:;=";"%") do @echo %~a`